# Marketing Cloud / Exact Target - Send - Error - Cancelled - why?

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, campaign, campaign-member

Our Administrator has left the business and I am taking over but I have had no experience with Exact Target as of yet.
We use Exact Target for sending out thousands of emails to different campaigns etc. On One campaign when we go through the process of sending it shows on the tracker as "error" then switches to "Cancelled" about 3-5 minutes after.

What can cause this, what should my approach be?

I've checked the campaign within Salesforce, it is active, all the members are there with correct member statuses etc - Really stumped to why this one campaign keeps failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, go to the send preview section of either classic or Email builder and preview using the list you are sending to.  If this does not display an error, next to try is the 'validation' tool in their system.  This will check your email for any validation errors and let you know what is causing them.

If the above options still do not show any errors, this is likely a 'send time' ampscript or SSJS error that is happening. Your best bet is to talk to SFMC support and ask them to send you the error logs on that send.  Unfortunately there currently is no way for us, as users, to access this.

The send log error will likely be technical, so have your developer or tech savvy coworker with you to look at it.